# recurrence with performSelector after delay

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

```
-(void)manageNetConnection{
    static BOOL closing=FALSE;
    NSLog(@"connecting Imap after net");
    if([imapStoreObj isStoreConnected] && closing==FALSE){
        [imapStoreObj close];
        NSLog(@"close store");
        closing=TRUE;
        [self performSelector:@selector(manageNetConnection) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

        return;
    }else if ([imapStoreObj isStoreConnected] && closing==TRUE) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(manageNetConnection) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

        return;
    }
    closing=FALSE;
    [indicatorForGetMail setHidden:NO];
    [indicatorForGetMail startAnimation:nil];
    netOff=2;
    NSLog(@"netOff==%d",netOff);

    [editFolderTable setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
    NSLog(@"connect net");

    [self reconnect];


}
```

This function is expected to call itself until connection is re-established. The problem is that the function doesn't calls itself after the specified delay.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with @performSelector. Use @performSelectorOnMainThread and NSTimer instead.

```
-(void)manageNetConnection{
    ...
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startTimer:) withObject:@"manageNetConnection" waitUntilDone:YES];
    ...
}

- (void)startTimer:(NSString *)data{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(endTimer:) userInfo:data repeats:NO];
}

- (void)endTimer:(NSTimer *)timer{
    NSString *target = [timer userInfo];
    SEL targetSelector = NSSelectorFromString(target);
    [self performSelectorInBackground:targetSelector withObject:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below line will call `-(void)manageNetConnection;` method for once after 5.0 if your both conditions are satisfying.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(manageNetConnection) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

Check for both if condition and else if condition satisfies.

```
if([imapStoreObj isStoreConnected] && closing==FALSE){

        [self performSelector:@selector(manageNetConnection) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

        return;
    }else if ([imapStoreObj isStoreConnected] && closing==TRUE) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(manageNetConnection) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

        return;
    }
```

or else you can use which repeats the call

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(testMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```